# My "vote map" program needs a "tweek"

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone and Merry Christmas to you all!
I am making a "vote map" program a bit like the one on Call Of Duty **JUST** as a practise for learning javascript.

It currently goes as I wanted it to be originally, but I want to take it a step further.
Currently if you run my program below, you will see there are two buttons with different maps on. You only are meant to have ONE vote and can literally only "spend" it on one map; the choice of map is allowed to be changed at anytime.

If you click map 1, the votes go up by 1, but no more if you click again.
If you click map 2, the votes go up by 1, but no more if you click again.

This only works once however. For example, I press map 1 and afterwards, I press map 2; this works perfectly, but when I try clicking map 1 again it doesn't work.

Remember I have only just started JavaScript; I thought this would be a good idea to practice, as it's common in Video Games.

Thank you for helping :D.

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong><i>Vote for your preferred map.</i></strong></p>
        <button id="map1" onclick="addVotes()">Forest Map </button>
        <button id="map2" onclick="addVotes2()">City Map</button>
        <p id="votesForMap1"></p>
        <p id="votesForMap2"></p>

        <script>
            var $num_of_votes = 0;
            var clicks_for_map_1 = 0;
            var clicks_for_map_2 = 0;
            var map1votes = 0;
            var map2votes = 0;
            document.getElementById("votesForMap1").innerHTML = map1votes;
            document.getElementById("votesForMap2").innerHTML = map2votes;

            var addVotes = function() {
                if (clicks_for_map_2 === 0) {
                    document.getElementById("votesForMap1").innerHTML = map1votes + 1;
                    if (votesForMap2 === 1) {
                        document.getElementById("votesForMap2").innerHTML = map2votes - 1;
                    }
                    clicks_for_map_2 = clicks_for_map_2 + 1;
                    $num_of_votes = $num_of_votes + 1;
                    if ($num_of_votes === 1) {
                        map1votes = map1votes + 1;
                        document.getElementById("votesForMap1").innerHTML = map1votes;
                    } 
                }
            }

            var addVotes2 = function() {
                if (clicks_for_map_1 === 0) {
                    document.getElementById("votesForMap2").innerHTML = map2votes + 1;
                    if (votesForMap1 === 1) {
                        document.getElementById("votesForMap2").innerHTML = map2votes - 1;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("votesForMap1").innerHTML = map1votes - 1;
                    clicks_for_map_1 = clicks_for_map_1 + 1;
                    $num_of_votes = $num_of_votes + 1;
                    if ($num_of_votes === 1) {
                        map2votes = map2votes + 1;
                        document.getElementById("votesForMap2").innerHTML = map2votes
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Lesson 1 - learn to layout your code - you have a lot of `if`s and no indentation which makes it hard to follow. (Dunno why it got downvoted - your question is perfectly clear and reproducible)

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tweak

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand well, and as you said:

> You only are meant to have ONE vote and can literally only "spend" it
>   on one map; the choice of map is allowed to be changed at anytime.

In this case, you should use a radio button.

But, if you want to accumulate the votes done by all users, you should think about using e.g Ajax to retrieve and update the voting counts in the server.

Please, correct me if I get it wrong.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Why on Earth did you down-vote this thread? I actually tried to keep it as clear as possible yet all you do is down vote it, but **HELP** at the same time?

Comment: Id didn't downvote ur thread!!! I never do that. It wasn't me. I actually want to help you.

Comment: It was you; it had been 20 minutes before someone responded and you were the first person to respond and I had had no down votes before you posted.

Comment: I assure u it wasn't me. U can consult who did it in the your tab vote. Verify it please!!!

Comment: 23 ppl viewed this thread so far. it could have been just anybody. just accept the help, academia offers instead of insulting him/her.

Comment: See, the vote was removed. It was blatantly Academia.

Comment: Please, verify ur tab votes, and u'll definitely see who did it!

Comment: @Academia: Votes are anonymous.

Comment: @FelixKling: You're wight. I just realize it!

Comment: @OliverTwist: How childish is it to a) complain about a downvote and b) accuse someone to have downvoted your question. Votes are anonymous, it could have been anyone. You will have a hard time here with such an attitude. Also, the downvote wasn't removed, you got an upvote. Could have been Academia for all you know, so I suggest you thank them instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I would tweak.  The reason is isn't working is that if you vote for map 2, there is no `else` condition when you vote for the first map again.

I would suggest that you make one vote function and reference the target element that was clicked on.  This will allow you to keep the logic together and more compact.  You can also add more maps without copying and pasting the same function over and over.